# d3 onclick to get the specific path/bar reference

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

if I have a d3/dc chart, and I set a click event handler like so:

```
    var data = [{
    "city": "New York",
        "neighborhood": "N/A",
        "hits": 200
}, {
    "city": "New York",
        "neighborhood": "Brooklyn",
        "hits": 225
}, {
    "city": "New York",
        "neighborhood": "Queens",
        "hits": 1
}, {
    "city": "San Francisco",
        "neighborhood": "Chinatown",
        "hits": 268
}, {
    "city": "San Francisco",
        "neighborhood": "Downtown",
        "hits": 22
}, {
    "city": "Seattle",
        "neighborhood": "N/A",
        "hits": 2
}, {
    "city": "Seattle",
        "neighborhood": "Freemont",
        "hits": 25
}];
var pieChart = dc.pieChart("#pieChart"),
    rowChart = dc.rowChart("#rowChart");
var ndx = crossfilter(data),
    cityDimension = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
        return d.city;
    }),
    cityGroup = cityDimension.group().reduceSum(function (d) {
        return d.hits;
    }),
    neighborhoodDimension = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
        return d.neighborhood;
    }),
    neighborhoodGroup = neighborhoodDimension.group().reduceSum(function (d) {
        return d.hits;
    });

pieChart.width(200)
    .height(200)
    .slicesCap(4)
    .dimension(cityDimension)
    .group(cityGroup);
pieChart.filter = function() {};

    var colorScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .domain(["San Francisco", "New York", "Seattle"])
            .range(["#D82C8C", "#17A7CF", "#E58304"]);

    pieChart.colors(colorScale);

rowChart.width(500)
    .height(500)
    .dimension(neighborhoodDimension)
    .group(neighborhoodGroup);

dc.renderAll();

var clickChart = d3.select("#pieChart")
clickChart.on("click",function(e){
      console.log(this)
      console.log(d3.select(this.parentNode))
})
```

I am trying to find a way to reference the specific path/bar/etc that I am clicking. So in the fiddle example I want to be able to grab the City that I am clicking, is that possible?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wqn5543e/1/)

Comment: Please use the `dc.js` tag for questions related to the charting library. `dc` is completely different (a desktop calculator) so I completely missed this question. Also it's not necessary to stick so many tags on questions - those are used to get attention for your question, and `javascript` people won't be able to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of selecting the `<div>`, just select the paths and get the datum (the first argument) inside the "click" function:

```
var clickChart = d3.selectAll("path").on("click", function(e) {
    console.log(e.data.key)
})
```

Here is your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1sbrng9n/

Comment: PS: this is a pure D3 solution. If you want a DC solution, please let me know so I'll delete this answer.

Comment: right, well I haven't been able to get this to work in the dc on("rederlet", function()...etc approach either. d3 was a bit closer at least....yes please share.

Comment: No worries. If you need the value of each slice, just use `e.data.value`.

Comment: also if I change to rect instead of path to try and grab from bar charts, e.data.key doesn't seem to work?

Comment: That's right. For the rects it is just `e.key` and `e.value`.

Comment: This is fine, but I'd use `chart.on('filtered', ...` because it's connected with the meaning of the chart not just its representation in the DOM. It will tell you all of the currently-filtered items, you don't have to worry about selectors, etc. If you go with the raw d3 way, it's better to namespace your event listener like `.on('click.yourtag', ...` so that it doesn't clobber other listeners.

Comment: @Gordon since some months ago I'm avoiding writing any answer in a question with DC tag (I saw that this was DC, even without the tag). That's why I told OP that I could delete the answer if  he is not ok with a "pure" D3 solution. As a D3 coder, I don't know DC and, because of that, it's best if I skip questions with DC tag, which I'll remember to do!

Comment: Not an issue, your solution totally works and it's good for dc.js users to know how to drop down to d3. dc.js is a leaky abstraction by design, so whenever there isn't a good way to do something, it makes sense to drop down to d3.