# dc.js/d3.js Is there a way to get all the selected slices,paths, etc on a pie/row chart?

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

Was able to get a click event working on a pie/bar chart working per this  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43371121/d3-onclick-to-get-the-specific-path-bar-reference), which returned the key/value of the path selected. I am simply wondering if there is a way to get at all the selected path/rect of a given chart within say a click like this?

I have basically tried:

```
d3.selectAll('g').forEach(function(d) {
   for (var prop in d) {
      if (d[prop].classList !=== undefined && d[prop].classList.contains('selected')) {
          var ( elem in d[prop].children ) {
              // I can see the path element there but have been unable to get at it
              console.log(d[prop].children[elem]);

          }
      }
   }
});
```

what I am trying to do is get at the path in order to get the d.data.key for all selected chart paths on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably look at the data rather than trying to reverse-engineer it from the svg elements.

It sounds like `chart.filters()` will give you what you want.

http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.baseMixin.html#filters__anchor

Comment: so I am trying to get all the selected nodes from all the charts on the page,  from a single path/rect click event. In an effort to filter values of a control outside of dc/crossfilter. I am not sure how I would achieve this with chart.filters()?

Comment: i don't understand your question. maybe this question will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27675327/storing-dc-js-filters-in-uri-and-restoring-them

Comment: is it normal for the iterations of calls to grow? I notice that I return filters from chart click events that it keeps return more and more results of the same element?

Comment: Um, no I don't think I've seen that. Sounds like a bug but I'd have to look at code to see whether it's a library bug.